# How to remove OBUF in the elaborated schematic design in vivado?

Tags: vhdl, vivado

[image]

I want to remove the obuf present at the output's of my schematic design.

Comment: This question is not [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stackoverflow. Consider asking on [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vhdl). or in a vendor forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can NOT remove the port from the schematic. You have to change the source code.

You did not provide the code but the OBUF disappears if you remove the output port from the module.

Comment: As I am new to this can you please tell how to remove output port from module